# How to remove from an array without using the classes Arrays, Collections, Set, or Map?

Tags: java, arrays

```
test[0] = "one";
test[1] = "two";
test[2] = "one";
test[3] = "three";
```

I want to remove all the occurrences of "one" but can't use the classes Arrays, Collections, Set, or Map. Thats why I'm stuck, if it wasn't for the restriction I would be able to remove them.

Comment: Why do you have such restriction?

Comment: Please be more specific. What is the intended result? `[null, two, null, three]`, `[two, three, null, null]` or `[two, three]`?

Comment: i need it to print [two, three]

Comment: You want to remove from an array without using an array. What do you mean by this? Does something like `Array.length` count as using an Array?

Comment: Then use a second array to store only the values that you want. Use a simple for loop for that.

Comment: Using array.length is allowed, and that's what I think I have to do, but I keep getting exceptions

Comment: @James Please can you include the code that throws exceptions in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a method like so:

```
public static String[] removeFromArray(String[] inputArray, String removeString) {
    int removeStringOccurences = 0;
    for (String currString : inputArray) {
        if (currString.equals(removeString)) {
            removeStringOccurences++;
        }
    }
    String[] result = new String[inputArray.length - removeStringOccurences];
    int index = 0;
    for (String currString : inputArray) {
        if (!currString.equals(removeString)) {
            result[index] = currString;
            index++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This first checks to see how many times the `String` we want to remove occurs and then creates a new `String[]` based on the length of the original `String[]` minus the times the undesired `String` occurs.

Running the following:

```
    String[] test = new String[]{"one", "two", "one", "three"};

    System.out.println("Before:");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));

    test = removeFromArray(test, "one"); //Call our method

    System.out.println("\nAfter:");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));
```

Results in:

```
Before:
[one, two, one, three]

After:
[two, three]
```

Comment: THANK YOUUUUU! It covers everything!

Comment: I have a question how can I create String[] result = new String[inputArray.length - removeStringOccurences]; as a type Variable like P[ ] result = new P[ inputArray.length - removeStringOccurences ]; it does not work.

Comment: @James, if it's an `Object` that you're dealing with, you'd have to check how many times an `Object P` had an occurrence of what you're trying to remove a different way. Defining the length of an Array should, however, stay the same, so once you've figured out the number of occurrences `P[ ] result = new P[ inputArray.length - removeStringOccurences ];` should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most appropriate way of solving your issue is to take all of the elements after the element, you want to remove, and shift them one to the front. But this would leave a trail of one unused element.
You could also create a new array without the element to remove.

```
public void removeFromArrayShift(Object[] arr,int index) {
    for(int i = 0;i< arr.length -1;i++){
         if(i >= index)
             arr[i]=arr[i+1];
    }
    arr[arr.length-1]=null;
}

public Object[] removeFromArrayNew(Object[] arr, int index) {
    Object[] n = new Object[arr.length - 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < n.length;i++) 
        if(i>= index)
            n[i] = arr[i+1];
        else
            n[i] = arr[i];
    return n
}
```

The later could be optimized with System.arrayCopy if you can access that. ;)